# How to structure a python project with three applications that use common module

Tags: python, python-2.7, architecture, module, projects-and-solutions

My project contains three Python applications. **Application 1** is a web app. **Applications 2** and **3** contain scripts downloading some data.

All three apps need to use a module **Common** containing a "model" (classes that are saved to database) and common settings.

I have no clue how to structure this project. I could create three directories, one for each application, and copy **Common** three times into their directories (doesn't seem right).

Another idea that comes to mind is; create a main directory and put there all files from **Common**, including **__init__.py**. Then, crete three subdirectories (submodules), one for each application.

Another way would be installing **Common** using pip, but that means I would have to reinstall every time I change something in that module.

In previous projects I used .NET - the equivalent in that world would be a Solution with four projects, one of them being **Common**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Install Common using pip in editable mode (option "-e") and then you don't have to reinstall every time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a similar project that is set up like this

```
project_root/
    App1/
        __init__.py
    FlaskControlPanel/
        app.py
        static/
        templates/
    models/
        __init__.py
        mymodels.py
```

Then, I run everything from `project_root`. I have a small script (either batch or shell depending on my environment) that sets `PYTHONPATH=.` so that imports work correctly. This is done because I usually develop using PyCharm, where the imports "just work", but when I deploy the final product the path doesn't match what it did in my IDE.

Once the `PYTHONPATH` is set to include everything from your project root, you can do standard imports.

For example, from my FlaskControlPanel `app.py`, I have this line:

```
from models.mymodels import Model1, Model2, Model3
```

From the App1 `__init__.py` I have the exact same import statement:

```
from models.mymodels import Model1, Model2, Model3
```

I can start the Flask application by running this from my command line (in Windows) while I am in the `project_root` directory:

```
setlocal
SET PYTHONPATH=.
python FlaskControlPanel\app.py
```

The [`setlocal`](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) is used to ensure the `PYTHONPATH` is only modified for this session.

Comment: Can the PYTHONPATH edit be replaced by a *.pth file?  It is easier to include in source control.

Answer (score 3):

Make standard Python modules from your apps. I recommend structure like this:

```
apps/
    common/
        setup.py
        common/
            __init__.py
            models.py
    app1/
        setup.py
        app1/
            __init__.py
            models.py
project/
requirements.txt
```

Basic setup.py for app common:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='common',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

Make similar setup.py for other apps.

Set editable "-e" option for your apps in requirements.txt:

```
-e apps/common
-e apps/app1
```

Install requirements with pip:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Editable option means that source files will be linked into Python enviroment. Any change in source files of your apps will have immediate effect without reinstalling them.

Now you can import models from your common app (or any other app) anywhere (in other apps, project files, ...).

Answer (score 2):

I like this approach

```
projects/
  __init__.py
  project1/
    __init__.py
  project2/
    __init__.py
  lib1/
    __init__.py
    libfile.py
  lib2/
    __init__.py
```

So, I need to cd into the projects folder.
To start a projects use

```
python -m project_name
```

This allows me to easily import from any external lib like

```
from lib1.libfile import [imoprt what you want]
```

or

```
from lib1 import libfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a structure like this:

```
project_root/
    app1/
        __init__.py
        script.py
    common/
        __init__.py
        models.py (all "common" models)
```

app1/script.py

```
import os, sys

# add parent directory to pythonpath
basepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..')
if basepath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(basepath)

from common.models VeryCommonModel
print VeryCommonModel
```

If you don't want to set the python path at runtime, set the python path before running the script:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/project_root
```

And then you can do:

```
python app1/script.py
```

Comment: so let's say I run file **app1.py** located in **project_root/app1**; the file starts with `import models.py`; but **models.py** imports **common.models** which is not in module search path (`ImportError: No module named common.models`)

Comment: Updated my answer, maybe that is what you were going for?

Comment: yes, this should work if you are ok with modifying path at runtime

Comment: I guess you can also set the PYTHONPATH before running the script to make sure "project_root" is in the python path.
run: "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/project_root"